# Find overlap rate among nodes based on the share of matching attributes

Tags: python

I need to identify the relative affinity between several nodes based on the number of matches on the array of attributes each node has.

```
N1 = [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5]
N2 = [A3, A5, B1, C7, C8, C9]
N3 = [A1, C5, B7, B1, A2, A3, A4, A5]
```

What I need to obtain in an automated fashion is this data:

```
N1 has 100% overlap with N3 on attributes A1, A2, A3, A4, A5
N1 has 40% overlap with N2 on attributes A3, A5
N2 has 33% overlap with N1 on attributes A3, A5
N2 has 50% overlap with N3 on attributes A3, A5, B1
N3 has 71% overlap with N1 on attributes A1, A2, A3, A4, A5
N3 has 43% overlap with N2 on attributes A3, A5, B1
```

What logic, python library should I use to calculate overlap for all combinations given a variable number of nodes and node attributes?

Comment: Why does N2 have 33% overlap with N3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [python Set.intersection method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection) to quickly find an intersection between two sets. This method is optimised based on python set's hashing algorithm. Here, I am assuming that the percentage overlap is calculated based on `len(intersection) / len(node)`.

```py
N1 = [A1, A2, A3, A4, A5]
N2 = [A3, A5, B1, C7, C8, C9]
N3 = [A1, C5, B7, B1, A2, A3, A4, A5]

array = [N1, N2, N3]
sets = list(map(
    lambda node: set(node),
    array
))

for i, node1 in enumerate(sets):
    for j, node2 in enumerate(sets):
        if i == j:
            continue
        intersection = node1.intersection(node2)
        percentage = round(len(intersection) / len(node1) * 100)
        print(f"N{i + 1} has {percentage}% overlap with N{j + 1} on attributes {str(intersection).strip('{}')}")
```

Note that the above example works if the attributes A1, A2, etc, are distinct and are hashable, for e.g., numbers, strings, etc. For your custom classes, you would need to write your `__hash__` method so that the objects are hashable and can be contained within sets. More info on `__hash__` method can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__hash__#object.__hash__).